# jQuery .on with multiple events using event delegation

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery 1.8.2 to bind multiple events to a single class using event delegation:

```
$(document).on("focus blur", ".myClass", function() {
    console.log("Ba da boom.");
});
```

Comment: What does the console say before crashing? And why are you binding to `document`? Couldn't you bind it to some nearer parent? That's the entire reason `.live()` was deprecated and replaced by `.on()`.

Comment: Seems to be working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/s8dR6/

Comment: Actually, I'm finding that the first code sample is working as long as I do not pair click and focus events.  The error appears as "<error>" right before Chrome crashes.

Comment: Sushanth is correct the code above works.  Error was due the combination of click and focus in my application.  I have changed my entry to show the correct code.

Answer (score 0):

You could either chain multiple ons or attach multiple events using a map.

**Chain multiple ons**:

Example:

```
$(document).on("focus", ".myClass", function(){
    //do something
}).on("blur", ".myClass",  function(){
    //do something else
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/MG8S7/4/

**Attach Events Using Map**:

Example:

```
$(".myClass").on({
  focus: function(){
   //do something
  },
  blur: function(){
    //do something else
  },
  mouseenter: function(){
    //do one more thing
  }   
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/MG8S7/9/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your code works fine, and thank you, however listing the events together like I have above works as well and looks a little more succinct.  I guess I should have answered the question instead of editing my question.  Sorry!